# Adding users to entity reference field by custom field

Tags: users, entities

I have added some custom fields to my D8 site's user profiles. Would it be possible to add users to a entity reference field on a node using one of these? For example phone number, as that is one of the fields. Or am I stuck referring to only the users username?

Comment: What is the ultimate goal? Are you trying to display fields of the author on the node? Or are you trying to show fields of any user selected within a field on the node? Or do you mean, use an entity reference field to select a user, but instead of the user it just pops in the phone number field in one of the fields of the node? Also is this 7 or 8?

Comment: The nodes are "groups", where the added users would be listed as participants. Also, if I can manage, the added users will have edit-permission on the node in question.

So, adding users by phone number (or email f.ex.) would be simpler for less "techy" users than the drupal username. If more information is needed, please advise.

Comment: So on each node you can add as many users as you want to it? So if your node content type was 'Team' and the team is composed of an unlimited 'user' reference field. And when you visit the team page, you want to display the list of users added to that team, and their phone numbers. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you can add as many users as wanted. No, I would like the ability to add the users to the field using f.ex. phone number or email - instead of using the user name (which is the normal behaviour). On the node I have them displayed using user name right now, but I would like to show the full name if available. Here is an example node: http://cc-moon.net/groups/integrated-market-dynamics-and-logistics

The bottom members in the right side list are drupal user accounts. :)

Comment: So you want to add the users on the node edit page using their phone number in the entity reference field instead of their username?

Comment: Also do you need it to autocomplete or would you be okay with just entering the phone numbers and letting it match up afterwards?

Comment: Yes! I guess either would be fine, auto-complete or not. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any field to lookup a user in a entity reference field. You just need 2 things: an entity reference View & a configured entity reference field.

1. Through the Views UI, you can add a *User* view with an *Entity Reference* **Display**. Add any fields to the View that you'll want to search on. Once your do, the **Settings** link next to **Format:Entity Reference list** will popup a modal that will let select your **Search Fields**.
2. After you've created your view, add your node's entity reference field. Set the **Reference method** to *Views: Filter by an entity reference view*. Where **View used to select the entities** is set to the view you created in step #1. Once the new field config is saved, you'll be able to search for any users based of the text values in the fields selected in **Search Fields**.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! This worked like a charm! I only have one follow-up question: I can now search for those fields, but only the user name is shown for auto-complete. Is there any way I could show the user name and email, f.ex.?